# Where am I incorrectly setting up this dynamic Next.js page that is causing an error in the build?

Tags: typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using the pages router (not App router) in Next.js and my backend data is being served from another local server using Laravel. Using Next.js 14 (latest as of right now)

Attempting to build a page that uses the structure: `/app/src/pages/category/[id].tsx` and also using both `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths` (because of the dynamic nature of the page itself).

When I do `npm run build` it starts building the pages (roughly 650 different total pages between this route and a few others). Every once in a while it fails with:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/category/279". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (/www/my-site/app/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/www/my-site/app/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/www/my-site/app/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:269:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

I tried running it and when those start to pop up I'll run the same query it's running in Postman and received no 500 error (or any other errors) just the data back just fine.

Some calls on the build seem to generate just fine. Some do not.

I know that there can be issues with data fetching from an API inside of `getStaticProps` but the documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/rendering/static-site-generation) uses fetching in a similar way to how I am using axios.

Here is my getStaticProps code (slightly adjusted for sample code):

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    const category = await axios.get(`/api/category/${params.id}`).then(({ data }) => data)
    const sectionData = await axios.get(`/api/category/data/${category.guid}`).then(({ data }) => data.data)
    const relatedCategories = await axios.get(`/api/category/${params.id}/related`).then(({ data }) => data.data)

    return {
        props: {
            category ,
            sectionData,
            relatedCategories,
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my getStaticPaths code:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const categories = await axios.get('/api/category?per_page=99999999').then(({ data }) => data)

    return {
        paths: categories.data.map((category) => {
            return {
                params: {
                    id: category.id.toString()
                }
            }
        }),
        fallback: false,
    }
}
```

I tried moving the axios call into a separate `/app/src/lib/category.tsx` file as I've seen suggested but that made it fail immediately (build process didn't work at all)

What am I missing here?

Additionally here is more of the code from `/app/src/pages/category/[id].tsx`:

```
const CategoryProfile = ({ category, sectionData, relatedCategories }: Profile) => {
    const router = useRouter()
    if (router.isFallback) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
    }
    const [videoPlayer, setVideoPlayer] = useState(<></>)
    const [videoId, setVideoId] = useState(category.video_id);

    const loadVideo = () => {
        setVideoPlayer(
            <VideoPlayer videoId={videoId} />
        )
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        loadVideo ()
    }, []);

    return (
        <AppLayout header={null} tabs={null}>
          {/* markup using props: category, sectionData, relatedCategories */}
        </AppLayout>
    )
}
```

Here is the code I attempted within `/app/src/lib/category.tsx` and then instead of the same code above I used the call `getCategoryData(params)` instead.

```
import axios from "@/lib/axios";

export async function getCategoryData(params) {
    const category = await axios.get(`/api/category/${params.id}`).then(({ data }) => data)
    const sectionData = await axios.get(`/api/category/data/${category.guid}`).then(({ data }) => data.data)
    const relatedCategories = await axios.get(`/api/category/${params.id}/related`).then(({ data }) => data.data)

    return {
        category,
        sectionData,
        relatedCategories
    }
}
```